# How to change SIZE of bootstrap button according to value in REACT

Tags: reactjs, button, react-bootstrap

I am new to React scene want some help in achieving the following design:

[image]

Above are buttons/widgets which represent that many number of items. I need to size the buttons/widgets according to the value in them and all should be in one `<div className="row">` all buttons/widgets are clickable and sorts the Table upon clicking.

Please guide me in achieving the above.
The `values` can be dynamic i.e it can me more than 6. For simplicity I defined them as `const` but they will come form `DB`.

```
const value1 = 3;
const value2 = 5;
const value3 = 5;
const value4 = 3;
const value5 = 15;
const value6 = 3;
.
.
.
.
return (
  <> 
    <Portlet fluidHeight={true} className="portlet--border-bottom-dark">
       <PortletHeader
         title={
          <>
            ...
          </>
         }
         toolbar={
          <>
            ...
          </>
         }
         <PortletBody fluid={true}>
            <Button variant="success" 
                    className="subscription-manager-buttons" 
                    size="sm" 
                    active>{values}</Button>
         </PortletBody>
    </Portlet>
  </>
)
```

Thanks.

### Update - Answer by @onuriltan : Result shown below:

[image]

Comment: Can you share your code or component?

Comment: @onuriltan Edited my question please have a look, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating an array from the values you are getting from api, and then map through the array and adjust your buttons with by multiplying some value, I used 10 here

```js
const values = [5,6,7,8,9]


return (
  <> 
     {values.map((value, idx) => (
          <Button
            key={idx}
            style={{width: value * 10}}
            variant="success"
          >
            {value}
          </Button>
      )})
  </>
```

Comment: How do I put it inside `<PortletBody></PortletBody>` ?

Comment: just put the `{ values.map(... }` part

Comment: Thanks a Ton. It Worked you just missed a `)` in the end before `}`. Will mark your answer. Also edit my question to show the result.